# Multiplying last row of matrix with the matrix's inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a square $n\times n$ invertible matrix, $a_n$ denote its last row, and $e$ be the $n\times 1$ (column) vector of $1$'s. This is likely a simple linear algebra property, but I am not so sure why
$$a_n^TA^{-1}e=1.$$
Writing out the terms of $A^{-1}$ as $b_{ij}$, this reduces down to
$$a_{n1}(b_{11}+b_{12}+...)
+
a_{n2}(b_{21}+b_{22}+...)
+
...
+
a_{nn}(b_{n1}+b_{n2}+...)
=1.$$
Unfortunately, this doesn't help me see the relationship between the $b_{ij}$'s and $a_{nj}$'s, let alone how some of the entries would cancel together. Is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: What is $A\cdot A^{-1}$? And hence, what is $a_n^TA^{-1}$?

Comment: Something is wrong. If $a_n$ is the last row of $A$, then $a_n^T$ is a column and cannot be postmultiplied by $A^{-1}$.

Comment: #Vedran, presumably by $a_n$ the OP denotes the column vector built out of the last row of $A$.  Admittedly, this is a strange thing to do.

Comment: @VedranŠego,vadim123: Sorry, yes, that is what I mean. I always follow the convention that symbolically, vectors are always represented as column vectors until transposed. I can see how that's deceiving here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the last row of $AA^{-1}=I$; we conclude that $a_nA^{-1}=e_n$, where $e_n$ is all zeroes except a 1 in the last position.  Lastly, $e_ne=1$ is clear.